# A weak form of the abc conjecture involving the definition of Hölder mean

Tags: number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory, means, abc-conjecture

I wondered about a weak form of the abc conjecture, see the Wikipedia [*abc conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Formulations) using the theory of generalized means, I mean this Wikipedia [*Generalized mean.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) We get the following claim, where $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ denotes the product of distinct primes dividing an integer $n>1$ with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$.

**Claim (Edited).** *On assumption of the abc conjecture* $\forall \varepsilon>0$ *there exists a constant* $\mu(\epsilon)>0$ *such that for triples of positive integers* $a,b,c\geq 1$ *satisfying* $$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=1\tag{1}$$ *and* $$a+b=c\tag{2}$$ *ones has*
$$c<\mu(\varepsilon)\left(\frac{\operatorname{rad}(a)^q+\operatorname{rad}(b)^q+\operatorname{rad}(c)^q}{3}\right)^{3(1+\varepsilon)/q},\tag{3}$$
*where* $q>0$.

Then from our construction we get/recover the formulation **ABC conjecture II** when $q\to0^{+}$ as a consequence of the theory of generalized means or Hölder mean.

> **Question.** I would like to know what work can be done about the veracity (thus unconditionally) of the inequality $(3)$ for the given conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$, $\forall\varepsilon>0$ as in the formulation of the abc conjecture, for the smallest real number $q>0$ that we can evoke. **Many thanks.**

To emphasize we are interesting in the smallest real number $q>0$ for which our weak form of the abc conjecture $(3)$ is true. I don't know if this kind of inequalities are in the literature.

Please if you want, add also concise feedback in a paragraph as companion of your answer for my **Question** or in comments about if previous claim can be potentially interesting.

I've added below references, on other hand now this post is cross-posted on MathOverflow [*On weaker forms of the abc conjecture from the theory of Hölder and logarithmic means*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359706/on-weaker-forms-of-the-abc-conjecture-from-the-theory-of-h%c3%b6lder-and-logathmic-me) as the MO **359706** post.

### References:

[1] P. S. Bullen, *Handbook of Means and Their Inequalities*, Dordrecht, Netherlands: Kluwer (2003).

[2] Andrew Granville and Thomas J. Tucker, *It’s As Easy As abc*, Notices of the AMS, Volume 49, Number 10 (November 2002).

Comment: As I said I don't know if similar inequalities are in the literature. Feel free to add your feedback about if this post is interesting, from here I can to improve. If you are interested I've asked in this site Mathematics Stack Exchange also the post *Weaker than abc conjecture invoking the inequality between the arithmetic and logarithmic means*, that is the post with identificator **3580506**

Comment: **It is appreciated if** some user provide his/her feedback about my post in comments, I mean if the idea to combine the definition and theory of Hölder means as I did with the formulation of the abc conjecture is potentially interesting. Also, it is appreciated the feedback for the mentioned post in previous comment MSE post **3580506** , an inequality  that I evoke as much more weaker than the abc conjecture , many thanks.